# SAPUI5 SAPUI5 XML model add item

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have an XML model bound to a table and I want to add a new row to the model. The XML data itself is rather simple:

```
<gettagevents>
<tageventlist>
    <tagevent>
        <time>2011-09-09T14:29:16.302Z</time>
        <factory>06</factory>
        <materialcode>21</materialcode>
        <serial>16999991231</serial>
    </tagevent>
    <tagevent>
        <time>2011-09-09T14:29:17.101Z</time>
        <factory>06</factory>
        <materialcode>21</materialcode>
        <serial>16999991232</serial>
    </tagevent>
</tageventlist>
```

Only relevant is the value for serial, so it would be enough for me to add a new serial number to the model. I have read about document.createElement, which I guess could work for me, but I do not get it working.

I have this part in my controller:

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("tbl_det3_rfid");
var oSerial = "1234567890";
var oModel = oTable.getModel();
var aData = oModel.getProperty("/tageventlist/tagevent/serial")
```

Can anyone help me how to get this done, so adding a new line to my model with the serial e.g. 1234567890?

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: How is your model currently binded to the table ?

Comment: in my xml view I bind the items like this: items="{path: '/tageventlist/tagevent'}"  and then use {serial} to display the value     and the binding itself      var oTable = this.getView().byId("tbl_det3_rfid");
                                   oTable.setModel(oRfidModel);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the [XML Model control](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel.html) allows you to add a new record. However you could get the XML object from the model and append a XML node to it using jQuery. After this you would have to update the model to see the new node in the table.

```
var oXML = oModel.getObject("/tageventlist");
$(oXML).append("<tagevent><time>2011-09-09T14:29:16.302Z</time><factory>06</factory><materialcode>21</materialcode><serial>16999991236</serial></tagevent>");
oModel.refresh();
```

Comment: Coming back to this issue above. Funny enough, the scenario above works in Chrome, but in IE it does not add the new line to the model. in Chrome, after refreshing the model, the new line is displayed, in IE it does not show. No error message, just the new line is not visible. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry didn't get the time to check this. I've posted a solution for your question on the new thread you opened.