# SAPUI5 XML model refresh not working in IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, sapui5

I had asked a question before how to add an item to add an item to a xml model:
[SAPUI5 SAPUI5 XML model add item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898699/sapui5-sapui5-xml-model-add-item)

The answer I got was working:

```
var oXML = oModel.getObject("/tageventlist");
$(oXML).append("<tagevent><time>2011-09-09T14:29:16.302Z</time>
         <factory>06</factory><materialcode>21</materialcode <serial>16999991236</serial></tagevent>");
oModel.refresh();
```

Until I now tested in IE11. Before, only tested in Chrome and it was working, so new line was added and after refresh visible. But in IE, the new line is not visible after refreshing the model. There is no error in the console. Any ideas why this could be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery append does not seem to add a childnode to the XML document, you can use the appendChild method on the XML node to append the newly created XML Element.

```
var oXML = oModel.getObject("/tageventlist");

var newTag = $.parseXML("<tagevent><time>2011-09-09T14:29:16.302Z</time><factory>06</factory><materialcode>21</materialcode><serial>16999991236</serial></tagevent>");
oXML.appendChild(newTag.documentElement);

oModel.refresh();
```